# Cordova Plugin Firebase not working with Ionic 3 run android

Tags: cordova, firebase, ionic-framework, angularfire

I am doing a test app using the plugin `cordova-plugin-firebase` to do Push Notifications, following this tutorial: https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/ionic-native-with-firebase-fcm-push-notifications-ios-android/ . The problem appears when I try to compile the project with android with the following command: `ionic cordova run android` giving me a build failed where the error is the follows: `Could not find support-v4.aar (com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0)`. Do you guys have some idea about this error? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do some changes in your build.gradle file inside platforms/android and need to add maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' } before the jcenter() as follows:

```
allprojects { 
  repositories { 
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' } //add this code
    jcenter() 
  } 
}
```

Comment: Amazing man, it works! Now the curiosity question: Why is this necessary? It is a bug problem or we should always do this type of stuff when try to add some native plugins? Anyway, thanks!

Comment: @Joan, this is now essential for new versions of google libraries. They moved their libraries out of the android SDK to the maven repo.