# Getting build failed error while exporting apk in ionic 3

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, ionic-framework, gradle

I am getting this error while exporting the apk.

```
FAILED
```

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.

  > Could not find support-v4.jar (com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0).
  >   Searched in the following locations:

  https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-v4/26.1.0/support-v4-26.1.0.jar
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info
  or --debug option to get more log output.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED
 in 39s
26 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 25 up-to-date
(node:13362) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: /home/nishanth/Desktop/ionic/Animia/platforms/android/gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.

  > Could not find support-v4.jar (com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0).
  >   Searched in the following locations:
  >     https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-v4/26.1.0/support-v4-26.1.0.jar
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 39s
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (/home/nishanth/Desktop/ionic/Animia/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/cordova-common/src/superspawn.js:169:23)
    at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:925:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:209:5)
(node:13362) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:13362) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

Comment: Please check this link for relevant answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51196432/cordova-plugin-firebase-not-working-with-ionic-3-run-android/51204497#51204497

Comment: @ChrisG your answer helped a lot